# Is it possible to swap fragments inside a background thread

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-asynctask, android-fragments

My idea was to create the new fragment inside an AsyncTask, then on onPostExecute i would swap it with the progress bar fragment that is shown. My problem is that the fragment is never swapped so it stays with the progress bar fragment. Is this not possible to do? Is it a bad approach? Should i have the progress bar inside the DetailFragment instead? (Will be a lot of fragments with progress bars in them)

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {      
    super.onStart();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, new ProgressBarFragment()).commit();
    TestSwapFragment d = new TestSwapFragment();
    d.execute(data);
}

class TestSwapFragment extends AsyncTask<FragmentData, Void, MyFragment> {

FragmentData data = null;

    @Override
    protected MyFragment doInBackground(FragmentData... params) {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(15000); // Simulate the long running method below
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {                  
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        this.data = params[0];
        DetailFragment df= new DetailFragment();
        df.ExecuteFragment(this.data); // Long running

        return df;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(MyFragment result) {               
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (this.data.Position == FragmentPosition.PaneOne)
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, result).commit();
        else
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame2, result).commit();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any theoretical reason why this shouldn't work. But said that, it's a very odd approach to me.

The `AsyncTask.doInBackground()` is generally used for creating/downloading/processing data, and the `AyncTask.onPostExecute()` is to update the UI. But you're distributing UI parts on both methods.

Furthermore the Fragment is a UI class, and you're using it to do data crunching, again mixing the purposes of each class. As a general rule, on my projects, I tend to follow something like that (just as example showing some generic names, but on the real stuff, use meaningful names, also I might be ignoring some constructors, just to keep it short)

```
MyActivity.java
public class MyActivity extends Activity{


      private class MyWorker extends AsyncTask<SomeDataObject, Integer, SomeDataListObject>{
            @Override
            protected MyFragment doInBackground(SomeDataObject... params) {
                 // in here we use SomeDataObject to generate the SomeDataListObject
                 return MyDataCruncher.processData(someDataObject);
                 // see it's a static method, process A and generates B, that's all.
                 // but very important that it's its own class, separate from Activity and Fragment
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(SomeDataListObject result){
                if(results != null){
                     // Here we create the fragment, pass the data to it and do the transaction
                     getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, MyFrag.newInstance(result)).commit();

                }else{ /* do some error handling or whatever */ }
            }
}
```

and then on your fragment you do:

```
public class MyFrag extends Fragment{
    private static String KEY_DATA = "_key_data_"
    public static MyFrag newInstance(SomeDataListObject data){
        MyFrag frag = new MyFrag();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        frag.setArguments(b);
        // it's important to make your data parcelable and pass it with a Bundle as part of the fragment life-cycle
        b.putParcelableArrayList(KEY_DATA, data);
        return frag;
    }

    // then inside onCreateView
     SomeDataListObject data = getArguments.getParcelableArray(KEY_DATA);
    // ---

}
```

hope it helps

Comment: Why is it important to make the data parcelable? (After rewriting then i realize that i need to pass in a specific class) Why not just create a method, setData() that set's a variable?  MyData _data; .. public void setData(MyData data) { _data = data; }

Comment: I said on the answer. That's because of the fragment life-cycle. If the fragment object is being destroyed, but the system needs the same fragment later (back button, rotation, adding to layout fragment already on the manager, etc) the system will pass the same Bundle to the fragment so it can be re-built. If you just create a function like that, this won't happen and your fragment will have a null data on those conditions.